# FullCalendar não apresenta o evento respeitando o horário

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com o FullCalendar, e não estou conseguindo mostrar corretamente os eventos em seus respectivos horários. Alimento o calendário com um Json (sistema em PHP):

```
[
   {
      "id":"13",
      "title":"Varredura no sistema - Verificar falhas e consert\u00e1-las",
      "start":"2017-05-04",
      "end":"2017-05-07",
      "allDay":"true",
      "className":"evento"
   },
   {
      "id":"16",
      "title":"Teste",
      "start":"2017-06-02",
      "end":"2017-06-02",
      "allDay":"false",
      "className":"evento"
   },
   {
      "id":"17",
      "title":"Teste com hor\u00e1rio",
      "start":"2017-06-09T10:30:00",
      "end":"2017-06-09T11:30:00",
      "allDay":"false",
      "className":"evento"
   }
]
```

Já li e reli a documentação e não consigo entender onde está o problema para que o evento não seja mostrado no horário correto! Apenas os eventos com duração "allDay", aparecem na linha correta.

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?! Gratidão, desde já!
[image: Aparecendo assim...]

Comment: "id":"16" está sem horário por isso está o dia inteiro, verificou se o JSON não esta quebrando por causa de acentuação "id":"17" me parece que tem acentuação.

Comment: @HENRIQUELOBO, retirei a acentuação e continua marcando como dia inteiro, inclusive os eventos com horário. =(

Comment: Depois que montou o array você esta convertendo para JSON ?

    echo json_encode(nome_array);

Comment: Exatamente isso!
  foreach($row as $key => $value)
   {
     if (is_string($key))
     {
  // Irá criar um array com o nome do campo 
  // como chave (Key) e o valor (Value).
  $fields[mysql_field_name($table,$i++)] = utf8_encode($value);  
     }
   }
   
   // $json_result é o array que receberá 
   // os valores do array $fields
  
   $json_result[ ] = $fields ;
}
 
**$JSON = json_encode($json_result);**
  
print_r($JSON);`

Comment: Tenta assim echo json_encode($json_result); no lugar                        
 $JSON = json_encode($json_result); print_r($JSON);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exemplo de como montar o array para depois retornar a o JSON object literal:

```
foreach ($aAgenda as $k => $v) {    
 $dados[] = array('id'    => $v->id,
                  'title' => $v->title,
                  'start' => $v->start,
                  'end'   => $v->end);
}
echo json_encode($dados);
```

Faz esse teste e verifique se vai aparecer certo no calendário, comenta o **foreach** e coloca esse codigo:

```
 $dados[] = array('id'    => 1,
                  'title' => 'Teste',
                  'start' => '2017-06-23 12:30:00',
                  'end'   => '2017-06-23 13:30:00',);

echo json_encode($dados);
```

Comment: Fiz assim e o resultado continua o mesmo... O evento que tem horário continua carregando na linha de evento do "Dia inteiro"... =(  Eu não sei nem mais pra onde mexer...

Comment: @WanessaMarques qual a versão do seu FullCalendar?

Comment: FullCalendar v1.6.4 - antiga.... mas vou atualizar a versão agora...

Comment: Mudei a versão e funcionou corretamente! Nem tinha me ligado que estava com a versão mais antiga. Muito obrigada pela ajuda e paciência!